# How to add inline css to html

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, inline-styles

I want to add some inline styles to my html website. I have my css code in a style file called copy.css. (As a background, I can tell that I am doing this because I want to put a big portion of code inline, and also I want to be able to have different inline css depending on my URL page. So having separate css files makes it more neat and manageable). The code inside my css file copy.css is now only:

```
/*  My inline styles  */
```

So, the result I want to get in my html is:

```
<style>/*  My inline styles  */</style>
```

I DO NOT want to get this code into my html (because it is a href and not a true inline):

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='copy-css'  href='https://www.HIDDEN.se/wp-content/themes/guru/copy.css?ver=6.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

The above <link ... /> code is generated by this code in a php file:

```
<?php 
function add_custom_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style('copy',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/copy.css');   
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_css' );
?>
```

I have also tried using wp_add_inline_style but can not figure it out...all I do is to fetch the href and not the content of copy.css.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/
You can paste your HTML & CSS there, and get your HTML with inlined CSS as a result.

Comment: It is inline, corrected the headline now.

Comment: No, I do not thinks so, I still want my css code to be in copy.css. The HTML, or more correctly the php, should fetch the styles from copy.css on the go and make it inline.

Comment: Then you should use this tool: https://github.com/northys/CSS-Inliner. 
It's a php library which allows you to merge your HTML & CSS into an HTML file with inlined CSS. This way your styles can be inlined on go.

Comment: I have never used github before...and also I want the load to be fast, since I am doing this to have a faster website. I think I can make my php file call an other php file (instead of css), in which I just echo what I want to inline: <?php  echo '<style>/*  My inline styles  */</style>';  ?>....now I just have to figure out how php files call upon each other...

Comment: `I want to be able to have different inline css depending on my URL page`...why not just tell the site to load a different CSS file (via a `<link` tag) depending on the URL, rather than trying to inline it on the fly? I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to be. PHP can control which CSS file's path is loaded into the link tag

Comment: I do not want <link tags...as they can be render blocking...I want it to be truly inline. From my comment above, I will try to solve it by having my php file calling upon and fetching from an other php file that is just echoing my style. I will call on a different php file depending on URL page.

Comment: If that's what you're worried about, there are better ways to solve render blocking than this. e.g. see https://web.dev/critical-rendering-path-render-blocking-css/, https://web.dev/render-blocking-resources/ (and others)

Comment: Also as I said above, you can make PHP print a different `<link` tag (or just a different filename within it) depending on the URL of the page, so you don't have to put all your different CSS files into the page just in case.

Comment: Also consider using a CDN to host the files, so they're delivered quicker to the client.

Comment: But if you really want to go down the PHP route, rather than loading a totally different PHP file each time (although _can_ do that by using `include` or `require`), think about just having a function which returns different CSS depending on a variable passed into it. Maybe you could even store that CSS in the database to make it very dynamic - but then you won't get any caching speed advantages which could be gained by using a CDN, for example.

Comment: I will look into all these advices. Regarding redeclaring style sheet assets, maybe there will be some layout shifts if the css is not render blocking. Smart advice about passing a variable (propably page URL) into a function. I have never heard about having CSS stored in a database...I do not think that it will be faster than the PHP route, but I will keep it in my mind as I could use it for something else. For the CDN storage, I could  load the css styles in the footer a second time using <link after the page load to not affect the speed but still have them in CDN.